# DC-DC boost Converter for a motor load

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, converter

To give some context I have a 250 watt DC motor It is powering an electric race car for a school race my class is competing in. The rules say I have to use a specific unmodified motor supplied by 2, specific 12 volt batteries for a total of 24 volts as the power supply. After a little digging I found out the motor is actually rated for up to 48 volts. I also found no where does it say I can't boost the voltage to get higher output of the motor. I tested it with two 18 volt batteries at 36 volts and the car flew! First I tried buying a Dc-Dc converter rated up to 40 amps with adjustable input and outputs. With no load it works great! With a load on the motor (fluctuating around 40 amps with one spike at 50) the voltage drops back down to 24 volts and does not go as fast as with the batteries. Is there a Solution for this problem

Comment: Please post info from the nameplate of the motor and converter